# How to make hive table match data using column names and not using ordinal positions

Tags: hadoop, hive

If I have a csv like -

```
colName1,colName2
col1Value,col2Value
```

and a hive ddl like -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tableName (
  col2 STRING,
  col1 STRING
 ) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION 'hdfs://location/to/testcsv/directory'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

//select col2 from tableName; gives col1Value
```

This is obviously because in case of text files hive matches column to data field by ordinal position matching. If the underlying file is parquet then the match is done using column names.

I was wondering is there is a hive SerDe someone has written or maybe some SerDe property I am missing that tells hive to map data field names with hive table column names, such that in above example it would return "col2Value" when col2 is queried, even though ordinal position of col2 in hive table and data file does not match.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the answer is "no". When you work with text data (for instance csv or tsv) the column position-name mapping is fixed by you DDL. The question is: what do need such SerDe for? there is no restrictions in `select` statement. Plus you can always select your column names using regex.

Comment: Right, better to have such functionality when csv files are provided by some external team and your team controls hive ddl. So, any re-arrangement of fields from the actual data providing team will break the functionality. Of course, the other workaround is to change csv -> parquet where name matching works just fine. Thanks for your reply though.